# IND-CPA game with a state-dependent Encryption Function that is insecure once

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

in the context of another setting I was asked the following question.

Suppose the IND-CPA game is played with a symmetric encryption function $E$ that keeps a state of how many encryptions have already been requested by the adversary $A$ during the execution of the game. $E$ always outputs $E(m)=E'(m)$, where $E'$ is an IND-CPA secure encryption scheme, except for the $i$-th request, where $E(m)$ is insecure and trivially reveals the plaintext $m$ instead of invoking $E'$. $i$ is polynomially bounded in the security parameter and $A$ does not know how $i$ is determined (it could be probabilistic and depending on the previous executions of $E$).

Intuitively, I'd  say that $E$ is not IND-CPA secure. An Adversary $A$ that just guesses the polynomially bounded $i$ and poses any challenge after $i-1$ encryption requests during the pre-challenge phase would always win the game if he correctly guessed $i$, which happens with non-negligible probability as $i$ is polynomially bounded. However, when trying to do a formal proof of this, I struggle to state an explicit $A$ with a non-negligible advantage, as this $A$ needs a precise specification of the upper-bound of $i$.

I'd be thankful for further discussion and tips about how one could solve my issue.

Comment: Doesn't $p(\lambda)$ (or was it $p(1^\lambda)$?) suffice as the upper bound?

Comment: I thought so, too, but I assume $A$ does not know the value of $p(\lambda)$. Just letting him guess $i$ with an upper bound of $n^c$, where c is constant, would be possible? Since in that case some Adversary $A_c$ exists with $p(\lambda) < n^c$, who then would have a non-negligible advantage.

Comment: As an unrelated side-note: such an encryption scheme is definitely not [left-or-right CPA secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/33281/23623), because you can just encrypt the same two messages until you get one back and deduce the bit from that (however this doesn't imply the security break you want).