# How can we reduce indistinguishability-from-random to other security notions?

Tags: encryption, randomness

In probabilistic encryption schemes, different notions of security exists.  I'm interested in the relationship between two notions.  One is the indistinguishability-from-random notion of security and the other is the right-or-left notion of security.  In crypto literature, it's often asserted that the former is stronger than the latter.  But is there a crisp proof of that?

In [Difference left-or-right CPA security, IND-CPA security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33279/difference-left-or-right-cpa-security-ind-cpa-security), the answer seems to indicate that Left-or-Right CPA security and Real-or-Random CPA security are equivalent.  However, I have found in other papers like [Rogaway's paper on Modes](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf) that Real-or-Random is a stronger notion.  On page 19, he defines the Real-or-Random security notion. On page 20, he defines the Left-or-Right notion among others.  Then he concludes: "In fact, the indistinguishability-from-random-bits notion is properly stronger than all four of the alternative notions sketched above."

Is there a proof for his claim or is this not settled in the crypto community?

Comment: Well in the link you provided, the answer seems to indicate that Left-or-Right CPA security and Real-or-Random CPA security are equivalent.  However, I have found in other papers like Rogaway's paper on Modes that Real-or-Random is a stronger notion. Is there a proof for his claim or is this not settled in the crypto community?

Comment: Sure here is the paper: https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf .  On page 19, he defines the Real-or-Random security notion.  On page 20, he defines the Left-or-Right notion among others.  Then he concludes: "In fact, the indistinguishability-from-random-bits notion is properly stronger than all four of the alternative notions sketched
above"

Comment: I incorporated your followup comments into the question.  Feel free to revert the change and/or make further edits and/or delete the comments now that they're redundant.

Answer (score 5):

Let $E_k$ be a cipher with a uniform random key $k$ unknown to the adversary.  Actually this can be any pseudorandom function family; its invertibility is not relevant in the chosen-plaintext attack model.  It might keep state, or it might be randomized; filling in the details of state and/or randomization is left as an exercise for the reader.  There are a few different ways to quantify attacks against $E_k$, usually phrased in terms of a random decision algorithm $A(\mathcal O)$ defined on an oracle $\mathcal O$ that may involve $E_k$.

- **Left-or-right indistinguishability.**  We define the oracle $\operatorname{LOR}(P_0, P_1) := E_k(P_b)$ where $b$ is a secret fair coin toss unknown to $A$, and the adversary wins if $A(\operatorname{LOR})$ returns $b$.

  That is, the adversary will submit a series of message *pairs* $(P_0, P_1)$, and our oracle always returns the encryption $E_k(P_0)$ of the left message, or the encryption $E_k(P_1)$ of the right message, and the adversary has to figure out which way it is.  The left-or-right advantage is $$\operatorname{Adv}^{\operatorname{LOR}}_E(A) := \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(\operatorname{LOR}) = b] - 1/2\bigr\rvert.$$  We measure the distance from $1/2$ because any answer given by $A$ that is *independent* of the oracle, and therefore of $b$, will always succeed with probability $1/2$; what's interesting is *how much better* $A$ can do by taking advantage of the oracle.
- **Real-or-random indistinguishability.**  We define oracles $\operatorname{Real}(P) := E_k(P)$ and $\operatorname{Rand}(P) := E_k(\tilde P)$, where $\tilde P$ is an independent uniform random message of the same length as $P$, and we will quantify how well the adversary can tell them apart.

  That is, the adversary will submit a series of messages $P$ to the oracle, and the oracle might return the ciphertext $E_k(P)$ for each message, or might return the ciphertext $E_k(\tilde P)$ of random gibberish $\tilde P$ of the same length as each message instead.  The real-or-random advantage is a measure of how well the adversary can distinguish these two oracles: $$\operatorname{Adv}^{\operatorname{ROR}}_E(A) := \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(\operatorname{Real})] - \Pr[A(\operatorname{Rand})]\bigr\rvert.$$

These two security notions are essentially equivalent, since the best advantage against one is at most double the best advantage against the other, as shown in [Bellare–Desai–Jokipii–Rogaway 1997](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/sym-enc.html).  There are other slightly weaker notions of security, like find-then-guess, which I usually just call IND-CPA, and semantic security, which is equivalent to find-then-guess but usually more of a pain to prove theorems about.

**Note that in the left-or-right and real-or-random settings, the adversary is always given *real ciphertexts* of partially unknown messages.**  LOR/ROR indistinguishability implies nothing about the shape of ciphertexts—ciphertexts could be written in pig-Latin encoded in KOI8-R, or in [Navajo binary](https://xkcd.com/257/), as long as the adversary can't tell two ciphertexts apart.

We can instead consider the difficulty of distinguishing *ciphertexts* from *uniform random bit strings* as in [Rogaway's CRYPTREC evaluation](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf):

- **Indistinguishable from uniform random.**  We define the oracle $F(P) := \tilde C$ where $\tilde C$ is an independent uniform random bit string of the same length as the ciphertext for $P$, and we will quantify how well the adversary can tell $E_k$ apart from $F$.

  That is, the adversary will submit a series of messages $P$ and get either the corresponding ciphertext $C = E_k(P)$ each time, or get an independent uniform random bit string each time.  The indistinguishability-from-uniform-random advantage is: $$\operatorname{Adv}^{\operatorname{PRF}}_E(A) := \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(E_k)] - \Pr[A(F)]\bigr\rvert.$$  (Called ‘PRF’ here because this is essentially the same notion as for pseudorandom function families.  In Rogaway's manuscript, it's called ‘ind\$’ because cryptographers apparently like to mark randomness with \$ signs.)

---

It is very easy to concoct a cipher that has left-or-right/real-or-random indistinguishability but is trivially distinguishable from uniform random: if $E'_k$ has LOR/ROR indistinguishability, define $E_k(x) = E'_k(x) \mathbin\| 0$ and you get a trivial distinguisher of the ciphertexts from uniform random bit strings, even though $E_k$ obviously still has LOR/ROR indistinguishability.  So clearly left-or-right/real-or-random indistinguishability *does not imply* indistinguishability from uniform random.

**How do we show that indistinguishability from uniform random implies left-or-right and real-or-random indistinguishability?**  Since left-or-right indistinguishability is equivalent to real-or-random indistinguishability, proving the result for ROR implies the result for LOR.  We will show that the real-or-random advantage of an adversary to distinguish *true ciphertexts* from *ciphertexts of uniform random plaintexts* is at most the sum of

- the adversary's advantage at distinguishing the *true ciphertexts* from *uniform random bit strings*, and
- a related adversary's advantage at distinguishing the *ciphertexts of uniform random plaintexts* from *uniform random bit strings*.

Let $A$ be a putative real-or-random distinguisher.

1. Note that the *oracle* for a real-or-random distinguisher is syntactically like the *oracle* for a uniform random distinguisher: it takes a plaintext, and it returns a ciphertext-length bit string.  So we can just as meaningfully evaluate $A(\operatorname{Real})$ and $A(\operatorname{Rand})$ as in the real-or-random setting, and $A(E_k)$ and $A(F)$ as in the uniform random setting.
2. By definition, $\operatorname{Real} = E_k$, so $A(\operatorname{Real}) = A(E_k)$.
3. Note that if $A(\operatorname{Rand})$ submits the plaintexts $P_1, \dots, P_n$ to its oracle, what it gets back are the ciphertexts $E_k(\tilde P_1), \dots, E_k(\tilde P_n)$ where the $\tilde P_i$ are independent uniform random plaintext bit strings.  So running $A(\operatorname{Rand})$ is equivalent to running $A'(E_k)$ where $A'(\mathcal O)$ works exactly like $A$ but queries $\mathcal O(\tilde P_1), \dots, \mathcal O(\tilde P_n)$ where $A$ would query $\mathcal O(P_1), \dots, \mathcal O(P_n)$.  That is, $A(\operatorname{Rand}) = A'(E_k)$.
4. Similarly, if $A(F)$ submits the plaintexts $P_1, \dots, P_n$ to its oracle, what it gets back are the ciphertexts $\tilde C_1, \dots, \tilde C_n$ where the $\tilde C_i$ are independent uniform random ciphertext-length bit strings.  It could just as well have submitted $\tilde P_1, \dots, \tilde P_n$ to its oracle, as $A'(F)$ would do, since $F$ ignores the input.  That is, $A(F) = A'(F)$.

We can combine these facts with the triangle inequality to set the desired bound:

\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{Adv}^{\operatorname{ROR}}_E(A)
    &= \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(\operatorname{Real})] -
         \Pr[A(\operatorname{Rand})]\bigr\rvert \\
    &= \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(\operatorname{Real})] - \Pr[A(F)]
       + \Pr[A(F)] - \Pr[A(\operatorname{Rand})]\bigr\rvert \\
    &\leq \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(\operatorname{Real})] - \Pr[A(F)]\bigr\rvert
       + \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(F)] - \Pr[A(\operatorname{Rand})]\bigr\rvert \\
    &= \bigl\lvert\Pr[A(E_k)] - \Pr[A(F)]\bigr\rvert
       + \bigl\lvert\Pr[A'(F)] - \Pr[A'(E_k)]\bigr\rvert \\
    &= \operatorname{Adv}^{\operatorname{PRF}}_E(A)
       + \operatorname{Adv}^{\operatorname{PRF}}_E(A').  \tag*{$\square$}
\end{align*}